# Python, sklearn: Order of Pipeline operation with MinMaxScaler and SVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, pipeline

I have a dataset that I want to run the sklearn SVM's `SVC` model on. The magnitudes of some values of the features are in the range of [0, 1e+7]. I have tried to use `SVC` w/o preprocessing and I either get unacceptably long compute times, or 0 true positive predictions. Thusly, I am attempting to implement a preprocessing step, particularly the `MinMaxScaler`.

My code so far:

```
selection_KBest = SelectKBest()
selection_PCA = PCA()
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", selection_PCA), 
                                  ("univ_select", selection_KBest)])
param_grid = dict(features__pca__n_components = range(feature_min,feature_max),
                  features__univ_select__k = range(feature_min,feature_max))
svm = SVC()            
pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), 
                     ("scale", MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))),
                     ("svm", svm)])
param_grid["svm__C"] = [0.1, 1, 10]
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(y = labels_train, 
                            n_iter = 10, 
                            test_size = 0.1, 
                            random_state = 42)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,
                           param_grid = param_grid, 
                           verbose = 1,
                           cv = cv)
grid_search.fit(features_train, labels_train)
"(grid_search.best_estimator_): ", (grid_search.best_estimator_)
```

My question is specific to line:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), 
                     ("scale", MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))),
                     ("svm", svm)])
```

I would like to know what the best logic is for my program, and thus the order of `features`, `scale`, `svm` in `pipeline`. Specifically, I cannot decide if `features` and `scale` should be switched from what it is now.

**Note 1:** I would like to use `grid_search.best_estimator_` as my Classifier model going forward for predictions.

**Note 2:** My concern is the correct way to formulate `pipeline` so that upon prediction step, the features are selected from the way it was done in the training step AND scaled.

**Note 3:** I notice that `svm` doesn't appear in my `grid_search.best_estimator_` result. Does this mean it is not being invoked correctly?

*Below are some results that indicate that order may matter:*

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("scale", MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))),
                     ("features", combined_features), 
                     ("svm", svm)]):

Pipeline(steps=[('scale', MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1)))
('features', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1, transformer_list=[('pca', PCA(copy=True, 
n_components=11, whiten=False)), ('univ_select', SelectKBest(k=2, 
score_func=<function f_classif at 0x000000001ED61208>))], 
transformer_weights=...f', max_iter=-1, probability=False, 
random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))])

Accuracy: 0.86247   Precision: 0.38947  Recall: 0.05550 
F1: 0.09716 F2: 0.06699 Total predictions: 15000    
True positives:  111    False positives:  174   
False negatives: 1889   True negatives: 12826


pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features),
                     ("scale", MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))), 
                     ("svm", svm)]):

Pipeline(steps=[('features', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1,
transformer_list=[('pca', PCA(copy=True, n_components=1, whiten=False)), 
('univ_select', SelectKBest(k=1, score_func=<function f_classif at   
0x000000001ED61208>))],
transformer_weights=None)), ('scale', MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=
(0,...f', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))])

Accuracy: 0.86680   Precision: 0.50463  Recall: 0.05450 
F1: 0.09838 F2: 0.06633 Total predictions: 15000    
True positives:  109    False positives:  107   
False negatives: 1891   True negatives: 12893
```

---

**EDIT 1 16041310:**
Note 3 resolved. Use `grid_search.best_estimator_.steps` to get full steps.

---

Comment: The SVM is in there, but seems to be hidden by whatever put that `...` in the output. `max_iter=1, probability=False` are parameters for `SVC`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @joeln. Do you know how to get the full, untruncated print out?

Comment: There is currently no way to get the full untruncated printout, I've realised: it is hard-coded in `BaseEstimator.__repr__`: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L148. Of course, you can repr each step alone...

Comment: it appears @maxymoo 's answer below helped w revealing the full printout , i.e., 'grid_search.best_estimator_.steps' (untruncated) vs. 'grid_search.best_estimator_' (truncated).

Comment: That only works because the length of each step is less than 500 characters.

Comment: works for me! should be enough for my work. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter `refit` in GridsearchCV (which defaults to `True`) which means that the best estimator will be refit against the full dataset; you will then be access this estimator with `best_estimator_`, or just with the `fit` method on your `GridsearchCV` object.

The `best_estimator_` will be the full pipeline, if you call `predict` on it, you'll get the same preprocessing steps as in your training stage.

If you want to print out all the steps, you could do

```
print(grid_search.best_estimator_.steps)
```

or

```
for step in grid_search.best_estimator_.steps:
    print(type(step))
    print(step.get_params())
```

Comment: Thanks @maxymoo . However, I am still unsure about my main dilemma: what is the best logic for the order of `features`, `scale`, `svm` in `pipeline`?

Comment: well i would say you've done the right thing by trying  both and comparing the accuracy ... from your results it looks like it doesn't really matter a whole lot ... 0.4% accuracy isn't hugely significant. However you may as well go with the one that's getting better accuracy ?

Comment: I agree that the minor difference in accuracy is better than the alternative in this case, and is comforting. However, if there was a large difference, then the order of pipeline would matter, and thus the correct pipeline order implementation and understanding would be paramount! This was point in asking this question.